# Outputting a list one element per line

Tags: python

I'm working on a scraper to scrape some company names and while it's working, I haven't been able to figure out how to output one company name per line instead of the following:

{'company': ['A.A.M.A.P. - ANTINCENDIO ESTINTORI PORTE TAGLIAFUOCO SEGNALETICA CORSI SICUREZZA LAVORO', 'A.G. SANITARI S.N.C. DI PIVATO & CASAGRANDE', "ABBIGLIAMENTO AL LAVORATORE LEVI''S; WRANGLER; LEE; RIFLE; ", 'BABY BAZAR NEGOZIO PER BAMBINI E NEONATI ABBIGLIAMENTO CARROZZINE PASSEGGINI GIOCATTOLI E USATO', 'BAIETTO ALBERTO ABBIGLIAMENTO', 'BAZAR MILANESE GIOCATTOLI BAMBINI INFANZIA - GADGET - PARTY ', 'BAZAR S.ANGELO - BIANCHERIA INTIMA SEXY', "BERTO''S ABBIGLIAMENTO"]}

I tried doing:

```
for elem in cmp_data:
    return elem
```

but then I just get the string "company" on each line instead of the actual company names.

Here's the full code:

```
import requests
import bs4

root_url = 'http://www.trevisoaziende.com'
index_url = root_url + '/settore-merceologico/aziende-01/page-'

def get_cmp_data(page_url):
    cmp_data = {}
    print ("pg: " + page_url)
    response = requests.get(index_url + page_url + '/')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    cmp_data['company'] = [a.get_text() for a in soup.select('td.lista_title > a')]

    return cmp_data

def show_cmp_list():
    for page_url in range(1, 16):
        print (get_cmp_data(str(page_url)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_cmp_list()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have isn't a list, it's a dict.  Do

```
for elem in cmp_data['company']:
    print elem
```

Alternately, when you define `cmp_data` instead of `cmp_data = {}` and `cmp_data['company'] = [...]` just do `cmp_data = [...]` to make it the list you seem to want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I am getting a company per line, however, it's printing a "None" at the end of each page. I tried to do "return elem" instead of print but then it only picks up the first company in each page. Any pointers as to what I may be doing wrong? I did change cmp_data to a list as you suggested.

Comment: Figured it out. Removed the "print" from show_cmp_list(). Now I'm getting what I want. Thanks again!